# Django View, get all list items in template

Tags: django, list

In Veiw, to get the selected item from an existing list in a template, I use request.POST.getlist('my_list').

In View, how to get all items from an existing list in a template?

In template I have:

```
<select id="list_permissions" multiple class="form-control">
{% for permission in permissions %}
    <option value="{{ permission.id }}">{{ permission.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I need to get all items in select id="list_permissions".

Comment: huh ? more context please !

Comment: make a xhr request with js to your server.put all selected elements in an array and send it via post to some url and write a function in your views.py which saves this array/whatever.

Comment: Using only Django is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must add a `name` attribute to a input if you want to send it to server.